# How to download paypal transactions using some API

Tags: transactions, web-services, download, paypal

Is it possible to download my paypal transactions using some kind of API? 
Scenario: I own a paypal account and don't want to download the files using the website export. Instead I want to download and process the transcations of my paypal account automatically.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, using the [TransactionsSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/transaction-search-soap/) API, I have been trying to do this with website standard, but I suspect you need website pro for this to work.

Comment: this api seems to support download of known transactions (by their ID) but not transactions from 1st of jan to 31st of jan. Besides that it requires full trust on the server calling that api.

Comment: @Uwe it does searches you can give it a date range. it does not require full trust, it needs an api cert which you can easily issue

Comment: Updated link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Any way around the 100 Transactions at a time limit?